# <p> element does not appear to be within parent <footer> element

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering why it appears as though these `p` elements are not positioned within their parent element, a `footer`.

My thinking would be that since the `p` elements are children of the `footer` element, they should be at the same location. But when I highlight the background of the `footer` using `background-color: red;` they are in entirely different locations, and it looks like the `p` stuff is displaced from the `footer` box at the bottom of the page, whereas the `footer` seems to be in the center. Here's the code I've been using:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(190, 33%, 58%);
  height: 500px;
}

header {
  background-color: hsl(190, 33%, 35%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  z-index: 2;
}

header .headerpos {
  position: relative;
  left: 135px;
}

header .headerpos h2 {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

body p {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  top: 250px;
  left: 325px;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="headerpos">
    <a href="home.html">
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </a>
    <a href="fruit.html">
      <h2>FRUIT</h2>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
      <h2>ABOUT</h2>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <p>
    The fruit site is an independent project that was created for the purpose of developing my skills with HTML and CSS. While the appearance and layouts are naive, the more I experiment with things, the more I learn!
  </p>
</body>
<footer>
  <p>Author: Person</p>
  <p>Contact: email@place.edu</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Despite your best efforts to keep `header` and `footer` outside of the `body` tag, the browser is going to put them in there. That means your CSS for `body p` is applying to _all_ `p` tags on your page. (@Quentin states this much more eloquently than I in his answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is invalid. This would be picked up if you had [used a validator](https://validator.nu/).

The `footer` element is not allowed to be a child of the `html` element (nor is the `header` element). You seem to have confused [the `body` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body) for [the `main` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) and [the `header` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) for [the `nav` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav).

Error recovery performed by the browser moves the `footer` and `header` elements so they inside the `body` element (where they are allowed).

This causes the CSS ruleset with the selector `body p` to apply to the paragraphs inside the `footer` and consequently moves their rendered location.

---

1. Write valid HTML
2. Adjust your CSS selectors to match your corrected HTML

Comment: @sean — No. Children are a subset of descendants. An element's grandchildren are not counted among its children.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with

```
body p {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 250px;
    left: 325px;
}
```

Try with this it will for your HTML

```
body > p {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 250px;
    left: 325px;
}
```

You HTML is invalid. Your Header and footer should be inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to place header and footer tags inside body.
   Two ways to resolve:
2. Write **p** tag inside a "div" or define a "class" to **p** tag in body, then give styles to that class. This way you can define styles for individual tags or elements.
3. If you need global styles or styles defined at "body p", then define styles to "footer p" as shown below.

solution:

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: hsl(190, 33%, 58%);
    height: 500px;
}

header {
    background-color: hsl(190, 33%, 35%);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    z-index: 2;
}

header .headerpos {
    position: relative;
    left: 135px;
}

header .headerpos h2 {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

body p {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 250px;
    left: 325px;
}

footer {
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

footer p{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 325px;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>About the Fruit Site</title>
    <link href="index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="headerpos">
            <a href="home.html">
                <h2>HOME</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="fruit.html">
                <h2>FRUIT</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="about.html">
                <h2>ABOUT</h2>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        <p>
            The fruit site is an independent project that was created for the purpose of developing
            my skills with HTML and CSS. While the appearance and layouts are naive, the more I experiment
            with things, the more I learn!
        </p>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <p>Author: Person</p>
            <p>Contact: email@place.edu</p>
        </footer>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved if you move the *footer* element inside the *body* element and then modify your CSS accordingly. The reason is because the *footer* element cannot be a child of the the *html* element.

```
<header>
  <div class="headerpos">
    <a href="home.html">
      <h2>HOME</h2>
    </a>
    <a href="fruit.html">
      <h2>FRUIT</h2>
    </a>
    <a href="about.html">
      <h2>ABOUT</h2>
   </a>
  </div>
</header>

<body>
  <p>
    The fruit site is an independent project that was created for the purpose of 
   developing my skills with HTML and CSS. While the appearance and layouts are 
   naive, the more I experiment with things, the more I learn!
  </p>
  <footer>
    <p>Author: Person</p>
    <p>Contact: email@place.edu</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```